# Converting from local coordinates to coordinates GPS?

Tags: convert, gps, coordinates

i am working with business object tool traying to make a kml file to be imported on google maps. I dont know much about geographic systems, but i begin to understand some basic things.

I have  a database which give me a local coordinates i know that because the gps has an appfile which has a grid configured and the database says me that units are meters.

The app file shows this information:

```
Site Point Pairs:   
        Number Of Points:   None

Ellipsoid:  
    Name:   (WGS 84)
    Semi Major Axis:    6,378,137.000
    Semi Minor Axis:    6,356,752.314
    Flattening: 1/298.2572215381
    Eccentricity:   
        First:  0.0818191911
        Second: 0.0820944382

Datum Transformation:   
    Name:   (WGS 84)
    Method: Molodensky
    Parameters: 
        Direction:  WGS84 to Local
        Translation X:  0.000
        Translation Y:  0.000
        Translation Z:  0.000

Geoid Model:    
    Name:   Subgrid of MEXICO97 (Mexico)    
    Method: Grid
    Geoid Grid File Name:   

Coordinate System:  
    Name:   12 North
    Group:  UTM

Projection: 
    Type:   Mercator Transversa
    Parameters: 
        Latitud central:    0°00'00.00000"North
        Longitud central:   111°00'00.00000"West
        Falso norte:    0.000
        Falso este: 500,000.000
        Factor de escala:   0.9996
    AZI Parameters: 
        Azimuth Direction:  North Azimuth
        Positive Coordinate Direction:  NorthEast
Embedded Data:  True
Embedded Geoid Grid Extents
Minimum Latitude:  30°53'60.0000"North
Maximum Latitude:  31°18'0.0000"North
Minimum Longitude: 247°03'60.0000"East
Maximum Longitude: 247°33'60.0000"East

CSIB Version: 10.50
CSIB Format: Big Endian
```

the database shows me this kind of values

```
vehicle     x          y          z

VE-28      328279     3457947    -48           
VE-28      328295     3459609    192         
VE-28      328288     3459617    193           
VE-28      328304     3459622    192           
VE-28      328220     3457362    -112
```

I would like to convert this unit into gps information through some formula.
or get the gps to give the gps coordinate to the database instead of the local coordinate.

Comment: Its called coordinate transformation or projection. http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html is one tool. http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26912/ is UTM12. 4326 is WGS84 (standard GPS output).

Comment: Check your database, if your database is spatially enabled there's a good change that already provides a build-in function for transforming coordinated from one system to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best method to visualize your data is the free software Quantum GIS. You can add your data with `Layer -> Add delimited text`. Select space as delimiter; x and y will be automatically selected.

From the information you gave, the projection is WGS84 UTM 12N, `EPSG:32612`.

You can add Google satellite background with the openlayers plugin to see if the points are on the right spot.

Then you can rightclick on the point layer `-> Save as`, select `keyhole markup language (KML)` as format, select a new filename, and `EPSG:4326` as CRS for the kml.

You can check to add the kml to the canvas, and the new points should fall on the same place as the first ones.

Comment: Thanks Andre, sorry for being late, I have a list with local coordinates in meter, if posible with this software to plot this local coordinates? how can i start i just downloaded this tool. Thanks in advanced

Comment: Andre, i have a list of local coordinates based in a base station, where do i put the information of coordinates of the base station, the local coordinates that i have are relatives to that base station, does this work for me even with this condition?

Comment: If you have the coordinates of the base station, use an excel sheet to calculate the sum of coo1(base) + coo2(relative to base). Then export as delimited text and add it as a new layer.

Comment: Thanks Andre, i got wrong the idea about coordinates are relatives to base station, it is only used for enhance the accuracy, the coordinates the database gives me are about the grid, thanks for your time your solution, software you suggested worked for me, thanks again. See you Andre, this site really rocks becouse of people like you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to have longitude and latitude (i.e. WGS84 coordinate system) instead of the projection used in your system. The key is to identify your source SRID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID) and your target SRID (i.e. 4326). If your database is postgis, check the    ST_Transform(geometry,SRID)    function.

Comment: Thanks Fabrice Marchal the database is oracle but i am not allowed to manipulate it, i have to do something out of it. I am goint to ask.