# OpenDroneMap Coordinate format

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, opendronemap

I was using OpenDroneMap to generate 2D map and the output comes with corner coordinates like this:

`-1.92011886596679688e+02 -1.89522613525390625e+02 1.91508605957031250e+02 1.99496490478515625e+02`

This does not look like normal lat/lng data, what format is this?

How should I convert to normal lat/lng?

Comment: That doesn't look right to me. What is this area meant to be (in lat/lon terms, roughly)? How did you do the processing and extract those coordinates?

Comment: Mine just outputs straight to lat long I think wgs 84?

Comment: What projection where the original images tagged in ?

Comment: The gdalinfo output is here: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/278 These 4 numbers are generated as accompany text file which confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem too so I figured I'd share my solution for future reference.

Turns out that these coordinates are a local projection coordinate system, and is used instead of latitude/longitude because it avoids distortion. Read [this article](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-vector-data-python/spatial-data-vector-shapefiles/geographic-vs-projected-coordinate-reference-systems-python/) for a better explanation of the differences.

First, you can extract the info for which EPSG zone you are in, as well as the bounding coordinates for the orthophoto. I did this following [this tutorial](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-raster-data-python/fundamentals-raster-data/intro-to-the-geotiff-file-format/), here is the basic code I ended up using:

```
!pip install rasterio

import rasterio as rio

orthophoto_path = "insert path here"

with rio.open(orthophoto_path) as lidar_dem:
  print(lidar_dem.crs)
  print(lidar_dem.bounds)
```

In my case, this yields me outputs of:

```
EPSG:32612
BoundingBox(left=338483.52535142255, bottom=6176391.54517328, right=338858.99250627175, top=6176778.7207066)
```

The EPSG indicates which zone you're in. After googling, I found info about my zone [here](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-12n/).

Then the bounds are actually in units of meters! It's rather handy. So in my case, you can see my survey is 387m tall (top - bottom). You can then use these numbers to relate where you are in accordance to your EPSG zone.

For me, this is all I actually needed to use (I didn't need lat/lon) since I just wanted to calculate distance from inside the image. However, if you did need to convert back to GPS, perhaps [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66015/converting-from-local-coordinates-to-coordinates-gps) will help you. Just keep in mind that lat/lon doesn't correlate linearly to distance on the surface of the earth. This is explained well by the first article I linked.